# Change MTP default action when connecting to Ubuntu

Tags: default-programs, mtp

The first time I've connected my smartphone to Ubuntu, it asked me about the default action each time I'll connect it.

Now the default action is to open nautilus.

How do I change it to not do anything or ask me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to system settings.

[image: system settings screenshot]

And then choose "Details"

[image: details screenshot]

Comment: Select "Never promt or start programs on media insertion" if you annoyed with  new window every time you connect your device